# elseif mysql query problem

Tags: php, if-statement

i'm having a little trouble with an elseif MySQL query i'm using to search my database depending on what selections are made in a form.

It's not returning an error, but its not returning the results it should, so i'm assuming the second elseif query isn't running at all. The first one works (when the right selections are made of course).

Can anyone point out what i'm doing wrong?

```
<?php
$jobtype = $_POST['jobtype'];
$country = $_POST['countries'];
$city = $_POST['cities'];

if ($jobtype=="All Jobs" && (isset($_POST['countries'])) && $city !="Whole Region") 
    {
  $result = mysql_query(
  "SELECT *
   FROM jobinformation 
   WHERE country = '$country' AND county = '$city'
   ORDER BY job_id DESC");

   if (!$result) 
     { 
      die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
     }

   $rows=mysql_num_rows($result);

   for ($j = 0; $j < $rows ; ++$j)
     {
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    echo 'jobtitle: ' . $row[3] .'<br />';
    echo 'Company: ' . $row[2] .'<br />';
     }
}

elseif ($jobtype=="All Jobs" && (isset($_POST['countries'])) && $jobtype=="Whole Region")

{

$result = mysql_query(
"SELECT *
FROM jobinformation
WHERE country = '$country'
ORDER BY job_id DESC");

etc etc (same as above)

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like this:

```
elseif ($jobtype=="All Jobs" && (isset($_POST['countries'])) && $jobtype=="Whole Region")
```

Should be this:

```
elseif ($jobtype=="All Jobs" && (isset($_POST['countries'])) && $city=="Whole Region")
```

You're check against `$jobtype` in the else if when you check it against `$city` in the if

Also if the first 2 parts of the if statement are the same you don't need an `elseif` here you can just use an else

Comment: @locirzak Thanks, my stupid oversight - thanks for clearing my eyes! Dan

Answer (score 1):

Despite not knowing what error you are having, please allow me to correct your code.

```
<?php
$jobtype = $_POST['jobtype'];
$country = $_POST['countries'];
$city = $_POST['cities'];

if ($jobtype=="All Jobs" && (isset($_POST['countries'])) && $city !="Whole Region") {
  $sql = "SELECT *
           FROM jobinformation 
          WHERE country = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($country) . "' AND county = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($city) . "'
          ORDER BY job_id DESC";
} elseif ($jobtype=="All Jobs" && (isset($_POST['countries'])) && $jobtype=="Whole Region") {
  $sql = "SELECT *
            FROM jobinformation
           WHERE country = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($country) . "'
           ORDER BY job_id DESC");
}

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  echo "jobtitle: {$row['jobtitle']}<br />";
  echo "Company: {$row['company']<br />";
}
```

This is a much better way to structure your code.

Comment: Thanks so much Ariel, i haven't got around to escape strings yet, i just wantyed to get everything working first. Thanks again, Dan

Comment: Note that I've changed a lot more than just escaping strings.

Answer (score 0):

In one spot you're checking `$jobtype` for "Whole Region", in the other you're checking `$city` for "Whole Region" - have you gotten the variables mixed up?